# How convert a binary to pdf in flutter

Tags: flutter, pdf-viewer, url-launcher

I have a variable to return in console:

[/PDF /Text /ImageB /ImageC /ImageI]
I/flutter (15515): endobj
I/flutter (15515): 10 0 obj
I/flutter (15515): << /Length 5716 /Filter /FlateDecode >> stream ...

in flutter, my pdf is genereated through post

```
    launchURL(String text) async {
    var response = await http.post(
        Uri.parse(
            "http://web.exampleExt.aspx"),
        headers: {"Accept": "*/*"},
        body: {'codigo': '10020014499'});
    print(response.body);

    return "success!";

}
```

so, my response.body is pdf but not visualizate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is the following:

```
Future<Widget> getAndShowPdf() async {
  var response = await http.post(Uri.parse("http://web.exampleExt.aspx"),
      headers: {"Accept": "*/*"}, body: {'codigo': '10020014499'});

  // Get the current directory
  final dir = await getExternalStorageDirectory();
  // Create a new File in the directory named pdfFromWeb.pdf
  final file = File("${dir.path}/pdfFromWeb.pdf");

  // Write down the file as bytes from the bytes getted from the HTTP request.
  await file.writeAsBytes(response.body.asUint8List());


  // Return a widget to view the PDF.
  return PDFView(
    filePath: file.path,
    enableSwipe: true,
    swipeHorizontal: true,
    autoSpacing: false,
    pageFling: false,
  );
}
```

This will work if and only if what your receiving on the body are bytes and you use a FutureBuilder to render the widget, you may also split the logic of the function in 2, one for creating a PDF File and the other one for rendering the PDF.

[flutter_pdfview](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_pdfview)

This may also interest you:

> [How to convert ByteBuffer to pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57111488/how-to-convert-bytebuffer-to-pdf/68320545#68320545)