# How to convert a PDF file to an image with Flutter?

Tags: flutter

How can I convert a PDF file into an image with `Flutter`?

I want to print the image to an ESC/POS printer using `esc_pos_printer`. This package won't accept `PDFImage`, it needs to be a Flutter `Image`.

I see plenty of PHP plugins that do this but nothing for Flutter.

edit: There is an answer to another [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55598481/how-to-decode-base64-pdf-string-in-flutter?rq=1) which shows some code to decode an image from "pdf64" but I can't figure out exactly what "pdf64" is.

I created a PDF from html using `flutter_html_to_pdf`like this:

```
Directory appDocDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
var targetPath = appDocDir.path;
var generatedPdfFile = await FlutterHtmlToPdf.convertFromHtmlContent(
    htmlContent, targetPath, targetFileName);
generatedPdfFilePath = generatedPdfFile.path;
```

Now I need to know how to create a Flutter Image from that PDF or the bytecode to send raw to the printer.

Comment: check out https://pub.dev/packages/printing

Comment: I did. I can't see how to connect that printer to 192.168.1.100:9100 otherwise I could use it.

Comment: `Printing` also wants a package version up to 16. It would not run until I removed the package.

Comment: I want to do the same thing. Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use https://pub.dev/packages/printing:

```
await for (var page in Printing.raster(document)) {
  final image = page.asImage();
  ...
}
```

This plugin can also convert your Html to Pdf with this:

```
final pdf = await Printing.convertHtml(
      format: PdfPageFormat.a4,
      html: '<html><body><p>Hello!</p></body></html>',
));
```

Comment: Use pdf_merger for converting pdf into image it supports both android and IOS. Before call this package make sure you allow read write permission.

https://pub.dev/packages/pdf_merger