# My question is how can I print an existing PDF via bluetooth thermal printer

Tags: flutter, pdf, thermal-printer, bluetooth-printing

How can I connect already loaded PDF into bluetooth thermal printer.

How can I connect already loaded PDF into bluetooth thermal printer.

Comment: AS far I know There is no simple way to send a pdf to a POS/thermal  printer. You would need to render the PDF and rasterize it into a bitmap that you can send line by line. It will be easier to get the transaction details and generate your own receipt by text/design by sending commands  to the printer

Comment: Kindly show me how to do it

Comment: " render the PDF and rasterize it into a bitmap"--- Kindly guide how to solve this, I haven't found any solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following plugin in `pubspec.yaml`:

dependencies:

```
  path_provider: ^1.6.27
```

Update the version number to whatever is current.

And import it in your code.

```
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
```

You also have to `import dart:io` to use the File class.

```
import 'dart:io';

 Future <List<int>> _readPDFFile() async {
      try {
        final Directory directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
        final File file = File('${directory.path}/my_file.pdf');
final bytes = File(file.path).readAsBytesSync();
      } catch (e) {
        print("Couldn't read file");
      }
      return bytes;
    }
```

use thermal printer package link = [bluetooth_thermal_printer: ^0.0.6](https://pub.dev/packages/bluetooth_thermal_printer/example)

finally send those bytes data into thermal printer

```
Future<void> printRecipientPaper() async {
    String isConnected = await BluetoothThermalPrinter.connectionStatus;
    if (isConnected == "true") {
      List<int> bytes = await _readPDFFile();
      final result = await BluetoothThermalPrinter.writeBytes(bytes);
      print("Print $result");
    } else {
      //Hadnle Not Connected Senario
    }
  }
```

if you have image in pdf file you can follow below link as well
[How to convert a PDF file to an image with Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59536583/how-to-convert-a-pdf-file-to-an-image-with-flutter)

Comment: // Sir can u check this program , here on clicking print I am reading DocumnetPDF() and then calling printTicket() to read the PDF and print. Please do check if this is correct.

Comment: I have emailed you the answer , kindly do check and reply.

Comment: To this Email ID: babul.sust.cse@gmail.com

Comment: My Email-Id : eby.hanson@microcentergmail.com

Comment: The way u discuss is fine. It should works. See thermal package implementation.

Comment: I have checked mail. your code seems to me fine. try to give a print if the result print as you desired mark answer as correct. happy coding.

Comment: But Sir In order to Print the answer contained in Bytes:

Comment: result = await BluetoothThermalPrinter.writeText(result!); My doubt doubt is how to pass the result to get printed either the above way or easing generator.text. Kinldly guide to code the answer.

Comment: result = await BluetoothThermalPrinter.writeText(result!) is not working /// Now going to try like this: //( I ahve passed result as parameter and taken as answer variable )/////////////////////////////////    printPDF(answer) async {
    // List<int> n_bytes = [];
    CapabilityProfile profile = await CapabilityProfile.load();
    final generator = Generator(PaperSize.mm80, profile);
    bytes += generator.text(
      answer,
      // styles: PosStyles(align: PosAlign.center),
      //linesAfter: 1
    );
  }

Comment: That also didnt worked

Comment: It would have been helpful if u could edit my  previous code attached in E-mail.