# Flutter: cannot download file from object url in webview

Tags: android, flutter, download, flutter-inappwebview

I need to download, from a mobile app developed in flutter 1.22.2, a file generated by a php script. The file is available in blob format.
The javascript code in the web page is:

```js
response.blob()
                .then(blob => URL.createObjectURL(blob))
                .then(url => {
                    let a = document.createElement('a');
                    a.href = url;
                    a.download = 'modulo-' + JobRiskIden + '.pdf';
                    a.target = '_blank';
                    document.body.appendChild(a);
                    a.click()
                    a.remove();
                })
```

Where "response" variable is the response from a fetch to a php page that generates the file.
I followed the instructions from this stackoverflow question:

[Flutter WebView blob pdf download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64865972/flutter-webview-blob-pdf-download)

The download works fine on iOS but an issue is present on Android (test done with compileSdkVersion 29): when I tap on the download link the debugger prints this message:

```
{message: Not allowed to load local resource: blob:https://apps.badgebox.com/62edb40f-4407-4d3b-8427-587ea133b778, messageLevel: 3}
```

Can someone help me to solve this issue?