# Cannot show/download pdf via flutter_webview

Tags: flutter, pdf, webview, flutter-inappwebview, url-launcher

I have this URL with [pdf resource](https://www.wmata.com/schedules/maps/upload/2019-System-Map.pdf)

I want to download it inside my app, but it doesn't work. I tried [url_launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher),
[flutter_cached_pdfview](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_cached_pdfview)
I tried this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64902313/7856586)
but no success.
For rendering site I use
[flutter_inappwebview](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inappwebview),

It works perfectly with
[flutter_custom_tabs](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_custom_tabs)
or opening the external browser, but it doesn't work in my app in web view.

How can I achieve pdf downloading inside my app via webview?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the other ones you mentioned, but `url_launcher` does not work with the `file:///` schema that you are probably using. If you are downloading the files to the application's directory, the file is usually (depending on the platform) secured with some permissions.

[`open_filex`](https://pub.dev/packages/open_filex) is a package, that uses `DocumentInteraction` for iOS and `Intent` for Android.