# Downloaded wrong blob file in the webview

Tags: javascript, android, flutter, google-chrome, webview

I have the web page, that renders an array of downloadable pdf files. Something like this:
[image]
In the browser I had a URL, that looked like this:

```
https://www.wmata.com/schedules/maps/upload/2019-System-Map.pdf
```

And I can easily download this URL.
In the webview I have the following URL after tapping:

```
blob:https://mydomain/7bc4fe9c-3405-4a86-bde2-944e1f15174d
```

I read lots of stuff where people recommend using js code to download blob files.
Like this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48954970/7856586) or here is [solution for flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64902313/7856586)

So, my js script looks like this:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var blobUrl = "blobUrlPlaceholder";
console.log(blobUrl);
xhr.open('GET', blobUrl, true);
xhr.responseType = 'blob';
xhr.onload = function(e) {
  if (this.status == 200) {
    var blob = this.response;
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(blob);
    reader.onloadend = function() {
      var base64data = reader.result;
      var base64ContentArray = base64data.split(",");
      var mimeType = base64ContentArray[0].match(/[^:\s*]\w+\/[\w-+\d.]+(?=[;| ])/)[0];
      var decodedFile = base64ContentArray[1];
      console.log(mimeType);
      window.flutter_inappwebview.callHandler('blobToBase64Handler', decodedFile, mimeType);
    };
  };
};
xhr.send();
```

As a result, I get HTML page with this text:
[image: text]

So, my questions are the following:

1. Can I reflect files on the webview as the web browser does? I mean files with the pdf extension, not as blob ones?
2. I guess I missed something put into the request in the js code, but how to know what should I additionally add? Why does the browser know it and the webview - does not?

I've also tested Chrome custom tabs, which work perfectly, but I must use Webview.
I tried [webview_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter) and [flutter_inappwebview](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_inappwebview) in the Flutter and native Android webview, but no success. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Why is the html source in the WebView different from the one 'in the browser'? And what do you mean with 'after tapping'?

Comment: `Can I reflect files on the webview as the web browser does?` ? What do you mean with reflect?

Comment: @blackapps I don't know why webview doesn't act like a browser. After tapping on icon I downloading file and url is different on the browser and webview

Comment: On the webview I have blob:.... on the browser  I have correct url with pdf. When I downloaded blob I had error

Comment: I asked you why you have a different one on the webview. Which icon? Start with the html source. Post it here.  Is it different? I asked it! And you explained nothing about 'reflect'.

Comment: @blackapps on the first screenshot we have download icon and after tapping on this icon we trigger url. In the browser this url looks like I wrote in the question with the .pdf extension and in the webview it is blob file. By using word reflect I meant, how to create pdf urls in the webview, how browser does. Browser did it automatically and web view - no

Comment: Please show html source. Third time i ask. A webview will not convert https to blob so lets see where this blob comes from.