# save response of http flutter

Tags: flutter, http, response

I made a model in which I go to get the various data, they are all ok except the 'card' in which I cannot save the data to its inside in my Model .. how can I save the data inside the 'card' of the Map you see in the picture?

[image: card]

```
    factory VoucherPdf.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    try {
      return VoucherPdf._(
        id: json.get('id') as int,
        orderId: json.get('order_id') as int,
        quoteId: json.get('quote_id') as int,
        createdAt: json['createdAt'] == null
            ? null
            : DateTime.parse(json.get('createdAt') as String),
        status: json.get('status') as int,
        card: json.get('card') as Map<String, dynamic>,
      );
    } catch (e) {
      logger.e('[VoucherPdf-fromJson] Deserializing error: ${e.oneline}');
      rethrow;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Are you getting any error? Please share it if you are.

Comment: @Josteve at the moment no error, but I cannot recall the data inside it, for example 'pdf'. i need to use the data in it but i can't recall it.

Comment: How are you trying to access pdf?

Comment: @Josteve   final voucherCanUse = widget.voucher.id;
              Connection()
                  .getGiftCardPdf(
                giftcardOrderId: voucherCanUse.toString(),
                userId: ContentBloc().state.userInfo.id.toString(),
              )
                  .then(
                (index) async {
                  var prove = index?.card.m;
                },
              );

i try with ' index?.card. ' but i not find pdf in my propriety..

Comment: Since card is a map, read the pdf like `index?.card['pdf']` and not `index?.card.pdf`

Comment: @Josteve oh fine work thanks, this gives me a base64 in string .. from this I have to generate a pdf to view. do you know how I can do?

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55598481/how-to-decode-base64-pdf-string-in-flutter

Comment: @Josteve thank you very much, all correct. if placed
'Index? .Card [' pdf '] and not index? .Card.pdf'

I do what to put your answer as final to close the post :)

Comment: I've added my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since card is a map, read the pdf like `index?.card['pdf']` and not `index?.card.pdf`